# How to find more than one match of numbers utilizing regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am attempting to pick apart data from the following string utlizing a regex expression:

`Ethane, C2  11.7310  3.1530  13.9982 HV, Dry @ Base P,T 1432.00`

The ultimate goal is to be able to pull out the middle three data points as individual values `11.7310, 3.153, 13.9982`

The code expression I am working with at the moment is as follows:

`(?<=C2  )(\d*\.?\d+)`

This yields a full match of `11.7310` and a Group 1 match of `11.7310`, but I can't figure out how to match the other two data points.

I am using PCRE (PHP) to create my expression.

Comment: The other two numbers are not preceded with `C2`. Your positive lookbehind can be changed to `(?<=C2  |  )` or simply `(?<=  )`. https://regex101.com/r/oa4r7R/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\G(?!^)|\bC2)\s+\K\d*\.?\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cT19Ia/1).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|\bC2)` - either the end of the previous successful match or `C2` whole word
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all the text matched so far in the match memory buffer
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `\.?` - an optional dot
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.